# loop in jquery tab different pages

Tags: jquery, loops, tabs

The code below I am going to use for more thank one tabs (to have something like tabs[i]) and I think would be better to have a loop:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.nav-tabs1 > li > a').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor

            var active_tab_selector = $('.nav-tabs1 > li.active > a').attr('href');  //get displaying tab content jQuery selector               
            var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs1 > li.active'); //find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
            actived_nav.removeClass('active');
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('active'); //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
            $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active'); //hide displaying tab content
            $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

            var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href'); //show target tab content
            $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
            $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in HTML it looks like:

```
<!-- item 1 Starts -->           
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                        <div class="ca-item-main">
                            <div class="ca-icon"></div>
                            <h3>Philosophie</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <!--<span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>-->
                                <span>Illustration d’une personne debout sur une pile de livres. Le cerveau de la personne est illustré. Nous voulons montrer que l’étude de la philosophie nécessite la lecture des théories anciennes et un travail réflexif.</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper">
                            <div class="ca-content">

<!--****************************Tab1 Starts********** -->

                            <section id="tab1" class="tab-content active">  
                                <h6>Définition</h6>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p> SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT</p></p>
                                </div></section>

<!--****************** Tab1 ENDs ******************** -->

<!--**********************Tab2 Starst********** -->

        <section id="tab2" class="tab-content hide">
            <h6>Similitudes avec la sociologie</h6>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p> SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT</p>
                                </div>

        </section>

 <!--********************** Tab2 ENDs ********** --> 

 <!--**********************Tab3 Starts********** -->     
        <section id="tab3" class="tab-content hide">
            <h6>Différences avec la sociologie</h6>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-close">close</a>
                                <div class="ca-content-text">
                                    <p> SOME TEXT SOME TEXT SOME TEXT</p>
                                </div>
        </section>
<!--********************** Tab3 ENDs ********** --> 

<!-- TAB nav starts -->

  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs1">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab1">Définition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab2">Similitudes avec la sociologie</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab3">Différences avec la sociologie</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- TAB nav ends -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- item 1 ENDs -->
```

So there are item1, item2, item3... and each of them has the same tabs (different descriptions). So. when I use this tab only once (for only in Item1's DIV) it works perfect but when I want to use for othe items' "DIV"-s it breaks.

Could you help me to make a loop because I am new in this area and would like to have professionals' help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be better if shown in a JSFiddle (with sample HTML)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I've added html code also

Comment: Here is a starting point JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/sSUvB/1/ Please update it to look like your issue :)

Comment: In short: `$(".ca-item").each();` to loop! Use `$(this).find()` for everything you grabbing in this item... dont use `id=` because you gonna have duplicate ID's, which is not allowd... you could use attribute `data-id=` and then select it with: `$("[data-id='#tab1']")`. hope it helps

Comment: please take a look here as you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/mamekay/E9eJ2/. Thanks!!!